# Can someone tell me what is wrong with my 'MsgBox' code?

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a Compile Error on this coding and can't figure out what is wrong with the line in red?

I have searched several sites to determine what might be wrong but haven't found anything that answers my issue?

```
    Sub MsgBoxCritical()


 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = Worksheets("Travel Expense Form")
 Dim amt As Range
 Set amt = Range("U15:U45")
 Dim proj As Range
 Set proj = Range("N15:N45")


   For Each Cell In ws("amt")
    If Cell.Value > 0 Then
   For Each Cell In ws("proj")
    If Cell.Value = "" Then Cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
        MsgBox "Project Number must be provided for all lines where 
        reimbursement is being requested" & vbCritical
        Cancel = True
   End If
End Sub
```

I am looking to present this message box when the workbook is saved if any cell in Column U, rows 15-45 are greater than 0 AND if the cell in Column N in the corresponding row is blank.

The compilation error I am receiving is on the line for Range U15:U45 and is an `Expected:Expression` error?

Comment: Give it a try with `For Each Cell in Range("U15:U45")` and check there if the value is bigger than 0. If it is, then check the one in "N" and throw a msgbox.

Answer (score 1):

Compile error means, that VBA cannot compile the code. Thus, it highlights the line that is "strange". In this case, the two If conditions are a bit wrong. This is the standard way to write `And`. It is written with 1 If:

```
Sub TestMe()

   Dim conditionA As Boolean
   Dim conditionB As Boolean
   conditionA = True
   conditionB = True
   If conditionA And conditionB Then
        MsgBox "Both true!"
   End If

End Sub
```

Concerning the code, there are some flaws in it. In general, if every cell from a range should be checked, then go for a loop and check it. In some cases, it is also possible to try `WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("U15:U45"))>0`, but it would be tough to get the row, which is above 0 in this case. Anyway:

```
Sub MsgBoxCriticalIcon()

    Dim myCell As Range

    With Worksheets("Travel Expense Voucher")
        For Each myCell In .Range("U15:U45")
            If myCell.Value > 0 And .Cells(myCell.Row, "N") = "" Then
                MsgBox "Project must be ... at row " & myCell.Row
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next myCell
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Your coding was much cleaner than the coding I was working on.  :)   However, it still doesn't seem to be working.  I have updated my original message with the new coding I had worked up.  I'm no longer getting an error but I am also not getting the message box.

Comment: Figured it out.  :)  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are two concerns with the MsgBox code as posted:

```
If Cell.Value = "" Then Cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
    MsgBox "Project Number must be provided for all lines where 
    reimbursement is being requested" & vbCritical
    Cancel = True
```

(Left the two surrounding lines of code in for context)

The first is that `vbCritical` is a flag and a separate parameter to the [`MsgBox` call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function). However, that would probably jsut put an unusual number at the end of the string.

The second problem is that your text lines have wrapped around and are presented on separate lines. This would cause a compile error.

Try this:

```
If Cell.Value = "" Then Cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
MsgBox "Project Number must be provided for all lines where reimbursement is being requested", vbCritical
Cancel = True
```

Note that  proper indentation will help you identify blocks of code and ensure that your `If` statements are properly matched. ALso, not sure what `Cancel` is doing in this loop, but learn about scope and how to properly pass variables (either as parameters or return them through functions).

Finally, always use `Option Explicit` at the top of the module. While this ensures strong typing and returns errors when you have undeclared variables (very useful for picking up typos), in this case it will also ensure the VBA IDE provides some additional information when debugging.

Comment: Perfect!!  Thank you for your help.  :)